# Socket.io doesn't emit from an app? (ionic)

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, websocket, socket.io

I use node.js as server and my ip is example.com:4000. So my endpoint of socket on server side should be example.com:4000. I manage to get it work even when I try to emit something from localhost to example.com:4000.

But when I have an app (I'm using ionic with a real device) but the socket seems didn't send it out the emit of socket.io. I wonder why, it has been 2 days I try to debug this issue.

my code on server side

```
var server = require("http").Server(express);  
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
server.listen(400);

io.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.on('msg', function(data) {
      console.log(data)
  });
});
```

client side

```
//angular service
.factory('socket',function(socketFactory){

    var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://example.com:4000');

    mySocket = socketFactory({
      ioSocket: myIoSocket
    });

    return mySocket;
});

//within my controller
socket.emit('msg',data);
```

To summarize, things worked on localhost but not when I try on an app?

Comment: Please post more detail, including your code, so people are able to help you.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @betseyb done, added my code.

Comment: and what is the error ?

Comment: @TiagoFabre no error, just that my server couldn't receive the emit from my app (mobile app)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code, since I know that example is working:

Factory

```
MyApp.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000');
    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Controller

```
MyApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, socket){
    $scope.users = [];
    socket.emit('connection'); });
...
```

Server side

```
"use strict";
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected!');
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
server.listen(9000, function() {
  console.log('server up and running at 9000 port');
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to say here? even my code is fine.